# GSON is serializing enum properly, but deserializes it as a String

Tags: java, serialization, enums, gson, deserialization

```
    HashSet<Skill> tmp = new HashSet<Skill>();
    tmp.add(Skill.WOODCUTTING);
    tmp.add(Skill.FIREMAKING);
    String j;
    System.out.println(j = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(tmp));
    System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(j, HashSet.class));
    for (Object e : new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(j, HashSet.class)) {
        System.out.println(e.getClass());
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

Skill is an enum defined like so:

```
@SerializedName("w") WOODCUTTING("Woodcutting"),
@SerializedName("m") MINING("Mining"),
@SerializedName("f") FISHING("Fishing"),
```

The output of the code above:

```
[11:04:18 INFO]: ["fir","w"]
[11:04:18 INFO]: [w, fir]
[11:04:18 INFO]: class java.lang.String
[11:04:18 INFO]: false
[11:04:18 INFO]: w
[11:04:18 INFO]: class java.lang.String
[11:04:18 INFO]: false
[11:04:18 INFO]: fir
```

As you can see, it first builds the Gson properly, but it then appears to deserialize it as a string rather than the enum. I'm a little lost as to what's going on here - aren't enums supported by Gson by default?

I've also tried registering a TypeAdapterFactory that's meant to serialize/deserialize enums. Although the write() method of the TypeAdapters it creates is called, the read() method never is.

Comment: Try to create a java bean and deserialize into it. Otherwise this won't work, gson can't understand that string is your Enum.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with the term java bean. Does that mean I make a class that has 1 variable of my enum type, and deserialize into that? The JavaDoc for Gson says "Gson provides default serialization and deserialization for Enums, Map, URL, URI, Locale, Date, BigDecimal, and BigInteger classes. If you would prefer to change the default representation, you can do so by registering a type adapter through GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Type, Object)." so why do I have to go through that extra step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a proper way of doing enum deserialisation with `Gson`.

```
List<Skill> items = new Gson().<List<Skill>>fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Skill>>(){}.getType())
```

Comment: great answer to go through

Comment: Worked for me, thank you so much! Incidentally, is there anywhere I can read up on this stuff? I didn't find that kind of information on the docs.. That syntax is pretty unusual and I don't think I ever would've figured it out on my own!

Comment: http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/Gson.html